# codeigniter url title special characters error

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, special-characters

I have a link that look like this:

```
www.localsite.dev/posts/332635955335419755
```

which works pretty well and i can see the post with ID = 332635955335419755

but when i try to add some of its text to the URL for prettier URLs... Codeigniter will show me a 404 page error if it has some special characters... actually it wont happen except you try to XSS or etc it... i dont get XSS'ed or such just throwing a 404 page error and if i remove the text after the ID it will work fine...

```
www.localsite.dev/posts/332635955335419755/<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT>
```

so how can i make sure not to get 404 error if the slug has these characters?

Comment: how can i make sure i wont get 404 error even if i use the 2nd URL with that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really how to prevent a 404, it's about how to make secure url slugs.

Have a look at the [following page from the user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html), you can use `xss_clean()` and / or `sanitize_filename()` to strip dangerous characters from a string. You probably want to do this before inserting your data in the db or when the slug is created.

There's also [the `url_title()` method](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) but I'm not sure how that would handle an xss string. Ideally you'd use a combination of all three methods - test it out.

Once you've done that you may still have to change the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` to allow whatever those two security methods let through but at least it should be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Change in config.php

```
  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

to

```
  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-<>/';
```

BUT - you really really really dont want to do that - it opens you up to MASSIVE security issues. You should re-think your approach to the problem. I would suggest you use a flash_message with the text, or even _POST it. Using a URL to handle that sort of text will just lead to issues and errors down the track...

Comment: so what if a user actually writes a post that contains `<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT>` then i will get the codeigniter error because of the permitted uri chars... isnt this wrong? should this be able load in url? or its better to remove open tags for example etc... so the slug will be clean

Comment: It all comes down to how your transmit data around your controllers. If you do it via the URL - then I think you will run into problems with URLs like the one above. You should just get users view the ID you had (the first link) - and then generate any additional data via your views + variable passing + _POST etc

Comment: well i thought to add slugs because of better SEO(?)... if there is one chance that a <<problem>> like above can happen.. because i cant control what users post... i will stick with IDs and see how i will deal with it later...